# OData V4 AddObject SetLink odata.bind does not trasmit related entities

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I've created a OData V4 Service described in the articles on the ASP.NET Homepage. 
I basically have a table Events where I assign Guests to. I need additional information to this many to many relationship, so I have created a EventGuest table.

Inserting Events and inserting Guests via OData just works fine. It just doesn't want to work, as soon as I want to insert related entities.

This is my Controller-Code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(EventGuest eventGuest)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _db.EventGuest.AddOrUpdate(eventGuest);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Created(eventGuest);
}
```

And this is how I want to insert the relationship. For the Client Code I use the official T4 template.

```
var ev = container.Event.FirstOrDefault();
var guest = container.Guest.FirstOrDefault();

var evGuest = new EventGuest();
evGuest.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
container.AddObject("EventGuest", evGuest);
container.SetLink(evGuest, "Event", ev);
container.SetLink(evGuest, "Guest", guest);

container.SaveChanges();
```

The request sent to the Server doesn't look too bad for me:

```
{"@odata.type":"#Entities.EventGuest","CreationTimestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","Guid":"adf500e3-e3a1-4841-883e-2322ed863321","ID":0,"Event@odata.bind":"http://localhost/odata/Event(1)","Guest@odata.bind":"http://localhost/odata/Guest(1)"}
```

So the Server tries to use `@odata.bind`, but unfortunately in the POST-Method of the Controller the referenced entities "Guest" and "Event" are null.

Comment: Not really. I changed my model so it would expose the ID properties for the foreign keys. In my request I set the ID and on the server I fetch the object with the ID out of the database. Then I can use the EF methods to do my CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the example at the MSDN Documentation? I noticed it always uses `AddLink` rather than `SetLink`, even in the `SetLink` documentation.

MSN Article is here: [DataServiceContext.SetLink Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.setlink%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)